# can't import module properly

Tags: python, opencv

First my folder structure(didn't show some of the unnecessary files or folders):

```
pythonLeaning
  |Debug
  |PythonLearning
     |Library
     |  |cameo.py
     |  |managers.py
     |
     |SciPy_etc
        |OpenCV.py
```

In the `cameo.py`, I have:

```
from managers import WindowManager, CaptureManager
```

And it works well.
But if I import these 2 file in `OpenCV.py`:

```
import managers
import cameo
```

I'll get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Amarth\Computer_Graphics\Programing\PythonLearning\PythonLearning\SciPy_etc\OpenCV.py", line 7, in <module>
    import managers
ImportError: No module named 'managers'
```

Visual Studio doesn't show any real-time error in the window, like red underline or something. And it can auto-complete the class or function name in `managers` and `cameo`, in which case I thinks indicates the success of the `import` .

Then what's the problem?

================Update 1=================

I thought I don't need `managers.py` since it is only used in `cameo.py`, so I deleted `import managers`, only left `import cameo`, now I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Amarth\Computer_Graphics\Programing\PythonLearning\PythonLearning\SciPy_etc\OpenCV.py", line 8, in <module>
    import cameo
ImportError: No module named 'cameo'
```

Comment: Python imports from the root of the structure (top down) try: from PythonLearning.Library import cameo

Comment: @martinB0103: I was posting the same comment :). Anyway, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383014/cant-import-my-own-modules-in-python) a similar question

Comment: @gionni Its one I have answered recently.....maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066129/python-module-not-found-issues-after-moving-directory/45066316?noredirect=1#comment77106277_45066316

Comment: @gionni solved, Thanks!